# Watchdog timer waking-up Pi after shutdown

Tags: watchdog

I would need the Watchdog timer of the Pi to kiss the halted Pi awake to make it boot again.
I know about the Watchdog timer limitations, and that it should not be able to do it, but I have seen reports of users that complain about the "unfortunate" setup situation, where the pi performs a shutdown, and the WD (apparently) makes it reboot right away. That's what I want.

This post explains why...

http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=44177&p=373587#p373587

Anybody?

Comment: Just wondering, why is this needed?  The Raspberry Pi doesn't consume that much power on it's own to keep it running.

Comment: The linked post goes to a 'move root to usb' post.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way, without a separate circuit or device to have the RPi wake itself up.  You could bridge the pins on [P6 Header](http://frustrateditengineer.wordpress.com/2013/01/27/see-how-to-make-a-reset-switch-for-your-rev-2-raspberry-pi/) using an Arduino or similar, or a physical switch or jumper on those same pins, or cut power and re-energize the system, but you can't have the RPi power itself on.

Comment: WoL has no use on the PI as it does not support a power down mode. Ethtool will report that the network part of the pi is capable of WoL but it is not supported.

Comment: @Kenneth Answer modified.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

The pi does not support -h since it is not capable of entering a powered down state. It is either on, as in running or it is not connected to a power supply. When you run shutdown -h it enters single user mode instead.

If you simply need a power cycle why not simply reboot:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, if you arm the watchdog on your Pi (with `nowayout=1`), then your Pi will reset (with the watchdog disabled) even if you `shutdown -h now` your Pi.

The only cases where you could be stuck are when the `watchdog` daemon is still working but something related to the network broke.

I have a Pi that I can't easily access, and I'm thinking of using the `ping` option of the [/etc/watchdog.conf](http://linux.die.net/man/5/watchdog.conf) file, using a public ip from from some big company to reboot the Pi if it loose internet connectivity.